# In Philippians 1:5, what does Paul mean by κοινωνίᾳ?

Tags: greek, word-study, grammar, philippians

> [Phl 1:5 YLT] (5) for your contribution to the good news from the first day till now,

> [Phl 1:5 NIV] (5) because of your partnership in the gospel from the first day until now,

> [Phl 1:5 NKJV] (5) for your fellowship in the gospel from the first day until now,

> [Phl 1:5 MGNT] (5) ἐπὶ τῇ κοινωνίᾳ ὑμῶν εἰς τὸ εὐαγγέλιον ἀπὸ τῆς πρώτης ἡμέρας ἄχρι τοῦ νῦν

I suspect that the preposition εἰς provides a good clue.

Also probably relevant:

> [Phl 1:7 NLT] (7) So it is right that I should feel as I do about all of you, for you have a special place in my heart. You share with me the special favor of God, both in my imprisonment and in defending and confirming the truth of the Good News.
>
> > [Phl 1:7 MGNT] (7) καθώς ἐστιν δίκαιον ἐμοὶ τοῦτο φρονεῖν ὑπὲρ πάντων ὑμῶν διὰ τὸ ἔχειν με ἐν τῇ καρδίᾳ ὑμᾶς ἔν τε τοῖς δεσμοῖς μου καὶ ἐν τῇ ἀπολογίᾳ καὶ βεβαιώσει τοῦ εὐαγγελίου συγκοινωνούς μου τῆς χάριτος πάντας ὑμᾶς ὄντας

Answer (score 1):

Philippians 1:5
New International Version

> because of your **partnership** in the gospel from the first day until now,

Thayer's Greek Lexicon

> STRONGS NT 2842: κοινωνία
>
> κοινωνία, κοινωνίας, ἡ (κοινωνός), **fellowship, association, community, communion, joint participation**, contact; in the N. T. as in classical Greek
>
> 1. the share which one has in anything, participation

For Philippians 1:5, the most relevant meaning is the follwoing:

> 2. contact, fellowship, intimacy: δεξιά **κοινωνίας**, the right hand as the sign and pledge of **fellowship** (in fulfilling the apostolic office), Galatians 2:9 (where see Lightfoot); τίς **κοινωνία** φωτί πρός σκότος; what in **common** has light with darkness? 2 Corinthians 6:14 (τίς οὖν **κοινωνία** πρός Ἀπολλωνα τῷ μηδέν οἰκεῖον ἐπιτετηδευκοτι, Philo, leg. ad Gaium § 14 at the end; εἰ δέ τίς ἐστι κοινωνία πρός Θεούς ἡμῖν, Stobaeus, serm. 28 (i. p. 87, Gaisf. edition)); used of the **intimate bond** of fellowship which unites Christians: absolutely, Acts 2:42; with εἰς τό εὐαγγέλιον added, **Philippians 1:5**; κοινωνίαν ἔχειν μεθ' ἡμῶν, μετ' ἀλλήλων, 1 John 1:3, 7; of the **fellowship** of Christians with God and Christ

By κοινωνίᾳ/partnership, Paul conveys a sense of intimacy and oneness with the Philippians in the gospel. They labor together for the sake of the gospel in one common goal.

My translation:

> because you have been my **partners in** the gospel from the first day until now,

"Partners" conveys more intimacy and "in" as we are **in** this together no matter what.

Comment: So are you suggesting a translation of "partnership" or "fellowship"? And how would you render εἰς? Thanks.

Comment: I added my translation.

Comment: Wouldn't εἰς suggest into, to, for (purpose)?   https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B5%E1%BC%B0%CF%82

Comment: Yes, it would. But "my partners into the gospel" sounds awkward to me.

Comment: What about "for", or "for the sake of"?

Comment: Sure but "in" is more intimate.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Your questions actually helped me to understand the verse better.